# Rails: Form not remembering all drop-down values when rendering my form with errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, simple-form

I'm using `simple_form` to submit a form with multiple fields and some dropdown values. When the form is rendered with errors,  all text fields are remembered, but some of the dropdown values are resetted. All values are permitted in strong params, and pass `validate_presence_of` validation.

The collections are created in my model using class methods. As follows:

```
def self.options
 ['One','Two','Three']
end
```

And loaded in my form using:

`<%= f.input :dropdown, collection: MyModel.options, include_blank: false %>`

What should I do correctly render the form object when it is returned with errors?

Comment: It should be done by simple_form automatically. Does model have your attributes after save was attempted?

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary, but you can pass `selected: @model.dropdown` option to your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f.select :dropdown, MyModel::myoptions, {include_blank: false}
```

And the method should be like this

```
   def self.myoptions
    [["One","One"],["Two","Two"],["Three","Three"]]
   end
```

Please try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the difference between MyModel.myoptions & MyModel::myoptions? Why exactly do you suggest putting the options into an subarray?

Comment: Since you are using 'self' while defining the method. To access class methods you need to use :: and to access instance methods you use . in Ruby

Comment: Thats how `f.select` works. one value would be for display and another one would be for the `value` attribute for the `<option>` tag. See the source it gets converted to using chrome tools or browser dev tools.

Comment: This works for me:  `f.select :dropdown, collection: MyModel::myoptions, include_blank: false`. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad it worked! Don't forget to accept my solution as answer ;)

Comment: Will do. Question: let's say you have ['one', 'one'] and wish the value to change per locale (but the key to stay the same). Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Good question, I haven't done in model it but may be you can have entries in locale files, and use I18n to do translations on view for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924326/rails-3-translations-within-models-in-production http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html